# Mock pyarrow.parquet using patch

Tags: python, pyarrow

Is possible to mock the declaration `import pyarrow.parquet as pq`?

I'm trying to mock it as:

```
@patch("twilio_events.workers.EngineDWH")
@patch("twilio_events.workers.pyarrow")
@patch("twilio_events.workers.s3fs")
def test_process_batch(s3fs, py, e):
    pass;
```

But it throws me an exception `Attribute Error....<workspace/myproject/twilio_events/workers.py'> does not have the attribute 'pyarrow'>`.

Other mocks are fine, only this one is throwing this exception :(.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The target of a patch is the name that needs to be replaced. In this case, if paraquet is imported as `pq`, you have to replace `pq`.

Try something like

```py
@patch("twilio_events.workers.pq")
```

This is [explained a bit in the docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id5)

> patch() works by (temporarily) changing the object that a name points to with another one. There can be many names pointing to any individual object, so for patching to work you must ensure that you patch the name used by the system under test.
>
> The basic principle is that you patch where an object is looked up, which is not necessarily the same place as where it is defined.